# Temporarily moving C++ Projects(VS2015) to Android OS ....compiler options?

Tags: android, c++

Is there a way to compile VS2015 C++ projects on Android?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing anything about your projects.

Comment: @ drescherjm It's hard to answer without knowing what you need to know about my projects, ...they are just standard library projects to C11 standard.

Comment: Do you use a GUI?

Comment: No, CMD only...

Answer (score 1):

Yup there are several options available but you can compile your programs in [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.cppdroid&hl=en) android apk.

Comment: Wont start without crashing for me, doesn't even show its gui.

Comment: Which android version you're using? and are you using it on a tablet or Mobile phone?

Comment: Sony Xperia Z4 10.1" Tablet + Android 7.1.1